# How to easily show a progress bar while a process running?

Tags: flutter

Is there any lightweight solution in Flutter that allows us to show a progress bar on the screen while an async function is executing?

```
ProcessIndicator( // just for example
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: handleSubmit,
        child: Text(isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register'),
    ),
),
```

Comment: `AnimatedBuilder` / `ListenableBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder`

Answer (score -1):

Yes lightweight solution here:
Check below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  void handleSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    // Simulating an async function call
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: isLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator() // Show progress indicator while loading
            : ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: handleSubmit,
                child: Text('Start Async Task'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```